# Is MongoDB a good choice for storing a huge set of text files?

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently building a system (with GCP) for storing large set of text files of different sizes (1kb~100mb) about different subjects. One fileset could be more than 10GB.

For example:

```
dataset_about_some_subject/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.txt
...

dataset_about_another_subject/
 - file1.txt
 - file2.txt
...
```

The files are for NLP, and after pre-processing, as pre-processed data are saved separately, will not be accessed frequently. So saving all files in MongoDB seems unnecessary.

I'm considering

1. saving all files into some cloud storage,
2. save file information like name and path to MongoDB as JSON.

   The above folders turn to:

   ```
   {
     name: dataset_about_some_subject,
     path: path_to_cloud_storage,
     files: [
       {
         name: file1.txt
         ...
       },
       ...
     ]
   }
   ```
3. When any fileset is needed, search its name in MongoDB and read the files from cloud storage.

Is this a valid way? Will there be any I/O speed problem?

Or is there any better solution for this?

---

And I've read about Hadoop. Maybe this is a better solution?

Or maybe not. My data is not that big.

Comment: For storing files exceeding 16MB document size, you can use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/index.html) collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, MongoDB has a maximum object size of 16 MB, which is below the maximum size of the files (100 MB). This means that, unless one splits, storing the original files in plaintext JSON strings would not work.

The approach you describe, however, is sensible. Storing the files on cloud storage such as S3 or Azure, is common, not very expensive, and does not require a lot of maintenance comparing to having your own HDFS cluster. I/O would be best by performing the computations on the machines of the same provider, and making sure the machines are in the same region as the data.

Note that document stores, in general, are very good at handling large collections of small documents. Retrieving file metadata in the collection would thus be most efficient if you store the metadata of each file in a separate object (rather than in an array of objects in the same document), and have a corresponding index for fast lookup.

Finally, there is another aspect to consider, namely, whether your NLP scenario will process the files by scanning them (reading them all entirely) or whether you need random access or lookup (for example, a certain word). In the first case, which is throughput-driven, cloud storage is a very good option. In the latter case, which is latency-driven, there are document stores like Elasticsearch that offer good fulltext search functionality and can index text out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your response! My use case will be the first one.So say I use cloud storage to save files, and save the metadata to some database, then MongoDB itself will be unnecessary, since any SQL or non-SQL can handle that information. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The metadata can be stored in any system including a typical SQL database, as this is small and structured.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to store large file using storage service provide by below. It also support Multi-regional access through CDN to ensure the speed of file access.

AWS S3: https://aws.amazon.com/tw/s3/

Azure Blob: https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-tw/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

GCP Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage

Answer (score 0):

You can rest assured that for the metadata storage you propose in mongodb, speed will not be a problem.

However, for storing the files themselves, you have various options to consider:

- Cloud storage: fast setup, low initial cost, medium cost over time (compare vendor prices), datatransfer over public network for every access (might be a performance problem)
- Mongodb-Gridfs: already in place, operation cost varies, data transfer is just as fast as from mongo itself
- Hadoop cluster: high initial hardware and setup cost, lower cost over time. Data transfer in local network (provided you build it on-premise.) Specialized administration skills needed. Possibility to use the cluster for parrallel calculations (i.e. this is not only storage, this is also computing power.) (As a rule of thumb: if you are not going to store more than 500 TB, this is not worthwile.)

If you are not sure about the amount of data you cover, and just want to get started, I recommend starting out with gridfs, but encapsulate in a way that you can easily exchange the storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer: as you say, 10GB is really not big at all. You may want to also consider the option of storing it on your local computer (or locally on one single machine in the cloud), simply on your regular file system, and executing in parallel on your cores (Hadoop, Spark will do this too).

One way of doing it is to save the metadata as a single large text file (or JSON Lines, Parquet, CSV...), the metadata for each file on a separate line, then have Hadoop or Spark parallelize over this metadata file, and thus process the actual files in parallel.

Depending on your use case, this might turn out to be faster than on a cluster, or not exceedingly slower, especially if your execution is CPU-heavy. A cluster has clear benefits when the problem is that you cannot read from the disk fast enough, and for workloads executed occasionally, this is a problem that one starts having from the TB range.

I recommend this excellent paper by Frank McSherry:

https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/hotos15/hotos15-paper-mcsherry.pdf